# Inserting Webservice data into SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: web-services, sql-server-2008, import

I am looking to import data that is currently stored in a webservice into new tables in SQL Server 2008.

Is this possible via a query? Examples would be helpful. The documentation that I have read thus far include either creating a webservice or using a Visual Basic template that does not exist in my version of VB (2008).

Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SSIS provides a "Web Service Task" -- I'd check that out first.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114%28v=sql.100%29.aspx